# Copying.tif files from one folder to another using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am trying to select specific Rasters and get all the supporting files copied over to a new folder.

For example:

I have a folder with .tif and supporting files:

[image]

So, I am trying to copy all the supporting files for BAND2 and BAND3 into another folder.

[image]

I did try some hands-on ModelBuilder, but could not get this to work:

[image]

Not sure how correct my approach is?

Comment: I think you should keep this question focused on ModelBuilder and ask about using ArcPy as an alternative in a separate question with a code attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Copying a spatial dataset within ArcMap\ArCatalog will transfer all the files, the GIS is "aware" of the supporting files.

From your screen shot of your folder I would use a FOR iterator as its the band number that changes the rest of the raster name is unchanging. You would then use inline variable substitution to build the full path name to the tif file and feed that into the copy tool. No need to use collects value or select data tools.

[image: Model]
*See how I use inline variable substitution to pass the output of the iterator into the file name.*